# What's this mold? (With microscopic images)

Tags: species-identification, mycology

So I (living in NRW, Germany) found an apparently quite homogenous mold colony at home, and would like to know what type of mold it is.

How I found the colony, where it grew:

- I ate something, then took a little nap, then woke up later a little nauseous. I blamed it on the food (which still is a plausible possibility).
- Then I noticed that my room smelled a little different from the stairwell (a little sour), and went searching for rotten stuff.
- I then found a large bowl with a little food leftovers and a huge mold colony.
- I remembered that some days prior, I removed a plate with food leftovers that was stacked on top that bowl, ironically because it had gotten moldy (with what looked like a different type of mold).
- Given that there was lots of mold in the bowl and I had removed the plate only some days prior if I remember correctly, the mold probably already grew in the bowl with the plate stacked on top, shielding it from light, and severely limiting air exchange, until I removed the plate, of course.

I made several images of the mold, one of the colony, which had grown on two leftover noodles, and several of the mold's structure, including its fruitbodies, under the microscope. All but the last two microscopic shots were made with the light coming from below, the last two shots were made with the light coming from above, if I remember correctly.

The images:

Image 1:

[image: Image 1]

Image 2:

[image: Image 2]

Image 3:

[image: Image 3]

Image 4:

[image: Image 4]

Image 5:

[image: Image 5]

Image 6:

[image: Image 6]

Image 7:

[image: Image 7]

Image 8:

[image: Image 8]

Image 9:

[image: Image 9]

Image 10:

[image: Image 10]

Image 11:

[image: Image 11]

Image 12:

[image: Image 12]

Image 13:

[image: Image 13]

Image 14:

[image: Image 14]

Image 15:

[image: Image 15]

Image 16:

[image: Image 16]

Comment: I'm no expert, but there's a key [here](http://website.nbm-mnb.ca/mycologywebpages/Moulds/Identification.html) - it has picture and text keys in links inside the page. I think possibly *Rhizopus* or *Mucor*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the "key", I didn't know such things existed.
With the help of the key, I now managed to form my own hypothesis of what fungus this is, tough I won't mention it to see if others independently arrive at the same answer, to check its "plausibility".

Comment: Keys of this sort have existed for a long time - I think it was around the 1700's they were invented. Certainly Lamark used them, but I think they were around before him.